# OrientDB query compare

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have the following doubt to query in OrientDB.

I have three vertex users, events and sports.

First users choose sports and at that point the has_sport edge is created, which has the 'out' on the user and 'in' on the sports.

And having some events registered by other users as follows, users-> events-> sports, users create edge 'out' and 'in' events and events edge 'out' and 'in' sports.

Now the question of how to do the query, I want to make a query that returns the events to the user according to the sports that he chose. In other words, to see if the user sports is equal to the events sport.

Vertex: users, events, sports
Edges: has_sport, has_event

[Image graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx5LW.png)

Sorry for my bad english hehe

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
    SELECT expand(event) FROM (
      MATCH 
        {class:users, as:user, where:(userId = ?)} -has_sport-> {as:sport},
        {class:events, as:event} -has_sport-> {as:sport},
        {as:user} -has_sport-> {as:sport}
    RETURN event
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using a MATCH statement:

```
MATCH 
  {class:User, as:user, where:(userId = ?)} -has_event-> {as:event} -has_sport-> {as:sport},
  {as:user} -has_sport-> {as:sport}
RETURN event
```

This will return the event RIDs. If you want expanded records, you can wrap it in a `SELECT expand()` eg.

```
SELECT expand(event) FROM (
  MATCH...
)
```

Comment: reviewing the model, I'm not sure it makes much sense... I mean, the user can choose a sport, but have events that match other sports he didn't choose... maybe I got something wrong, but I hope you got the idea on how to write the query

Comment: Hi Luigi, thanks for answer and sugestion. 
I put an image of the graph to get a better idea.

The idea is the following the user registers in the system and chooses the sports that it likes.

If there are events created by other users with the same sport is presented to him to participate.

Otherwise there is nothing displayed.

I want then in this query to verify if the user's sports are the same as the sports of the events.

Thanks for showing me the "MATCH" I will continue testing here in other ways, this is still not ideal.

Comment: Luigi, I put a query that worked for what I need there below the "EDIT" of the question.
I would like you to see if this query is in accordance with the best practices of OrientDB.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Luigi! Your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works..

```
select out.name as sports, in('has_event').name as eventname from (select expand(out('has_sport')) from User where userid = 151)
```

Please verify the "out" / "in" logic. if required change it.

Comment: Thanks Vineeth!! But it's still not the query I need, I'll keep trying here.

I put a picture for a better understanding of the problem.

Thank you again